# Why didn't == operator string value comparison make it to Java?

Tags: java, programming-languages, operators

Every competent Java programmer knows that you need to use String.equals() to compare a string, rather than == because == checks for reference equality.

When I'm dealing with strings, most of the time I'm checking for value equality rather than reference equality. It seems to me that it would be more intuitive if the language allowed string values to be compared by just using ==.

As a comparison, [C#'s == operator checks for value equality for string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766492/c-sharp-overloading-operator-versus-equals)s. And if you really needed to check for reference equality, you can use String.ReferenceEquals.

Another important point is that Strings are immutable, so there is no harm to be done by allowing this feature.

Is there any particular reason why this isn't implemented in Java?

Comment: You might want to look at Scala, where `==` is object equality and `eq` is reference equality (http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596155957/AdvancedObjectOrientedProgramming.html#EqualityOfObjects).

Comment: Just as a note, and this may not help you, but as far as I remember, you can compare _string literals_ with an '=='

Comment: @Kgrover: you can, but that's just a convenient by-product of reference equality and how Java aggressively optimizes string matching literals into references to the same object. In other words, it works, but for the wrong reasons.

Comment: @tdammers Yep, I agree. It was just a point I was trying to make.

Comment: IIRC, in C#, the ``==`` operator always maps to equals() method (when objects are involved) - probably because that's the more common case; Reference identity requires an explicit function call.

Comment: @aviv the `==` operator only maps to `Equals` if the `==` operator was implemented that way. The default behavior for `==` is the same as `ReferenceEquals` (actually, `ReferenceEquals` is defined as the object version of `==`)

Comment: @l46kok You don't need to prepend String before `ReferenceEquals`. `ReferenceEquals` is defined in the Object class and since everything implements Object, you don't need to qualify it with the class name, not even in static classes and structs.

Comment: @aviv: The `==` token represents two different operators.  If the types on either side of it define an equality-test overload, it binds to that.  Otherwise, if both arguments are reference types, and either they have subtype/supertype interface or at least one is an interface, then it tests reference equality.

Comment: Is there really a better answer than 'because they're two different objects'? Maybe a code example would be more helpful?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I wan't really talking about C#, but perhaps my question will be better understood if I phrase it a little differently for you.. what are some reasons people may have for using C#'s String.ReferenceEquals() rather than C#'s == for two Strings?

Comment: @jason9187, the follow-up question to that, "why?", might answer the original question (if coming from a usage perspective rather than language-design perspective). I also specifically mentioned 'false' in my question because I already know reference comparison is faster, but non-interned Strings can provide a false-negative. What's some use cases for wanting a false-negative on Strings?

Comment: @Anonsage:  When you really want to know whether or not it's two different string objects, perhaps to find out if the string is interned or not.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, excellent! Now, we are getting somewhere. I probably should have written those alongside the original question. So, the ultimate thing that I would like to know is what's a use case for wanting to know if a string is interned or not (at the language-user level, not language-developer level)? And/or, what's a use case for wanting to know whether or not it's two different string objects? Thank you, I'm sorry for the confusion, I'll update the question with the clarification.

Comment: It's a consequence of design decisions which make a lot of sense in many other scenarios. But since you seem to know that and be asking this anyways, I feel compelled to counter your question: Why does there have to be a use case for String reference comparison?

Comment: I made the jump from Java to C# _years_ ago. I started using "==" to compare strings for some reason and never really noticed this difference between the two languages until I read this question.

Comment: @Jacob Raihle: I agree, I can't imagine a valid use case for String reference comparison. If someone does it, it's either a special optimization for equals(), where it's known that all strings fulfilling equals() are in fact the identical reference, or it's an abuse of Strings for something else than representing a bunch of characters.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I guess it's just consistency, or "principle of least astonishment". String is an object, so it would be surprising if was treated differently than other objects.

At the time when Java came out (~1995), merely having something like `String` was total luxury to most programmers who were accustomed to representing strings as null-terminated arrays. `String`'s behavior is now what it was back then, and that's good; subtly changing the behavior later on could have surprising, undesired effects in working programs.

As a side note, you could use `String.intern()` to get a canonical (interned) representation of the string, after which comparisons could be made with `==`. Interning takes some time, but after that, comparisons will be really fast.

Addition: unlike some answers suggest, **it's not about supporting operator overloading**. The `+` operator (concatenation) works on `String`s even though Java doesn't support operator overloading; it's simply handled as a special case in the compiler, resolving to `StringBuilder.append()`. Similarly, `==` could have been handled as a special case.

Then why astonish with special case `+` but not with `==`? Because, `+` simply doesn't *compile* when applied to non-`String` objects so that's quickly apparent. The different *behavior* of `==` would be much less apparent and thus much more astonishing when it hits you.

Comment: Special cases add astonishment.

Comment: Strings were a luxury in 1995?  Really?? Look at the history of computer languages.  The number of languages that had some type of  string at the time would far outnumber those that did not.  How many languages besides C and it's descendents used null terminated arrays?

Comment: @WarrenT: Sure, some (if not most) languages had *some* type of string, but Unicode-capable, garbage-collected strings were a novelty in 1995, I think. For example, Python introduced Unicode strings with version 2.0, year 2000. Choosing immutability was also a controversial choice at that time.

Comment: @JoonasPulakka Then maybe you should edit your answer to say that. Because as it stands, the “total luxury” part of your answer is quite wrong.

Comment: Interning has a cost: you get a string that will never ever be deallocated. (Well, not unless you use your own interning engine that you can throw away.)

Comment: @Joonas If you went back to 1962, let's say, and asked a COBOL programmer about how much he wanted the "luxury" of garbage collecting or this dream you have of this crazy character set you call "Unicode", he'd probably say "What the heck do I want that for?"  If they don't apply to the environment you work in, nobody cares.  In that case, it would become an annoyance.

Comment: Is interning even guaranteed to exist on *every* implementation of the JVM and Java that follows the pertaining sections of the JLS? And regarding the new string in switch feature, how is that least-astonishment? It seems like a special case that can't use a straight-up `equals()` or `==` either way.

Comment: I believe you have to `intern()` *both* operands of the `==` in order to be safe.

Comment: Using String.intern() is usually not a good idea. See https://shipilev.net/jvm-anatomy-park/10-string-intern/

Comment: There was a LOT of discussions back then about how much memory was wasted by having 16-bit characters with 8-bit values (this has been fixed since). Unicode strings were a novilty then.

Answer (score 32):

[James Gosling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Gosling), the creator of Java, explained it this way [back in July 2000](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c_family_interview.htm):

> I left out operator overloading as a fairly personal
>   choice because I had seen too many people abuse it in C++. I've spent
>   a lot of time in the past five to six years surveying people about
>   operator overloading and it's really fascinating, because you get the
>   community broken into three pieces: Probably about 20 to 30 percent of
>   the population think of operator overloading as the spawn of the
>   devil; somebody has done something with operator overloading that has
>   just really ticked them off, because they've used like + for list
>   insertion and it makes life really, really confusing. A lot of that
>   problem stems from the fact that there are only about half a dozen
>   operators you can sensibly overload, and yet there are thousands or
>   millions of operators that people would like to define -- so you have
>   to pick, and often the choices conflict with your sense of intuition.

Comment: Ah, yes, the old "lets' blunt the pointy tool so  the oafs won't hurt themselves" excuse.

Comment: Good points. I once had a discussion with a colleague (we both use C++) about operator overloading. I said that it can be confusing because when I see an operator I have to look up a variable declaration to determine a variable's type, and then look up the type declaration to see if the operator is overloaded. In his opinion it was not that much of a problem, but then it turned out, while working on our code, he'd been using a certain overloaded operator the wrong way for months.

Comment: @Blrfl: If a tool creates more problems than it solves it is not a good tool. Of course, deciding whether this is the case with operator overloading could turn into a very long discussion.

Comment: -1. This doesn't answer the question at all. Java *does* have operator overloading. The `==` operator is overloaded for objects and primitives. The `+` operator is overloaded for `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, `String` and probably a couple of others I forgot. It would have been perfectly possible to overload `==` for `String` as well.

Comment: @Jorg - no it does not. Operator overloading is impossible to define at the user level. There are indeed some special cases in the compiler but that hardly qualifies

Comment: @AZ01: I think Jorg's point is that the programming language could have defined == as a special case as easily as + was defined as a special case.  This would not conflict with James' belief that Java users should should not be trusted with operator overloading.  James may believe that providing == for string would be confusing, but this particular quote does not offer any support for that conclusion.

Comment: @Blrfl: I don't mind the oafs hurting themselves. It's when they accidentially poke my eye out that I get annoyed.

Comment: @Blrfl The whole point of Java was to blunt the sharp things.  Elsewhere in that article Gosling mentions pointers and array bounds enforcement and the overall drive for reliability in what was expected to be a set-top platform.

Comment: @RossPatterson:  Even Ada, which by comparison makes Java look like a scalpel, has operator overloading.

Comment: The problem with operator overloading is that nearly everyone who (ab)uses it doesn't bother to create proper mathematical structures (rings, groups, etc.) leaving everything behaving in a strange way when you try to understand it thoroughly. If people could only only overload by implementing a strict interface (but then got it automatically), it would be a lot less objectionable.

Comment: [Guy L. Steele](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guy_L._Steele) famously said "_...the ability to define your own operator functions means that a simple statement such as x=a+b; in an inner loop might involve the sending of e-mail to Afghanistan._"

Comment: The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18) calls the operators + and - "additive operators". This sure ain't "operator overloading", it is just a special syntactic fairy dust. I approve of this.

Comment: @RossPatterson C# put back on place Operator Overloading, and everybody is using it without shooting themselves on the foot.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, the difference is that `+` for `String`s doesn't have a **competing interpretation**, while `==` does. Put differently: `s1 + s2` doesn't have any surprising semantics, while `s1 == s2` potentially could.

Answer (score 9):

Consistency within the language. Having an operator that acts differently can be surprising to the programmer. Java doesn't allow users to overload operators - therefore reference equality is the only reasonable meaning for `==` between objects.

Within Java:

- Between numeric types, `==` compares numeric equality
- Between boolean types, `==` compares boolean equality
- Between reference types, `==` compares reference equality

  - Use `.equals(Object o)` to compare values

That's it. Simple rule and simple to identify what you want. This is all covered in [section 15.21 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21).  It comprises three subsections that are easy to understand, implement, and reason about.

Once you [allow overloading of `==`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx), the exact behavior isn't something that you can look to the JLS and put your finger on a specific item and say "that's how it works," the code can become difficult to reason about.  The exact behavior of `==` may be surprising to a user.  Every time you see it, you have to go back and check to see what it actually means.

Since Java doesn't allow for overloading of operators, one needs a way to have a value equality test that you can override the base definition of. Thus, it was mandated by these design choices.  `==` in Java tests numeric for numeric types, boolean equality for boolean types, and reference equality for everything else (which can override `.equals(Object o)` to do whatever they want for value equality).

This is not an issue of "is there a use case for a particular consequence of this design decision" but rather "this is a design decision to facilitate these other things, this is a consequence of it."

[String interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning), is one such example of this. According to the [JLS 3.10.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5), all string literals are interned. Other strings are interned if one invokes `.intern()` on them. That `"foo" == "foo"` is true is a consequence of design decisions made to minimize the memory footprint taken up by String literals. Beyond that, String interning is something that is at the JVM level that has a little bit of exposure to the user, but in the overwhelming vast majority of cases, should not be something that concerns the programmer (and use cases for programmers wasn't something that was high on the list for the designers when considering this feature).

People will point out that `+` and `+=` are overloaded for String. However, that is neither here nor there. It remains the case that if `==` has a value equality meaning for String (and only String), one would need a *different* method (that only exists in String) for reference equality. Furthermore, this would needlessly complicate methods that take Object and expect `==` to behave one way and `.equals()` to behave another requiring users to special case all *those* methods for String.

The addition of auto boxing/unboxing of primitive wrappers (e.g. java.lang.Integer, etc.) muddles things a bit because comparing an `int` with an `Integer` (or vice-versa) with `==` will indeed compare the integer values of each of those things, but if both variables are of type `Integer` then using `==` may give an unexpected answer where the integer values are equal but the references are different, yielding a `false` comparison.

The consistent contract for `==` on Objects is that it is reference equality only and that `.equals(Object o)` exists for all objects which *should* test for value equality. Complicating this complicates far too many things.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer. This would be a great answer on the other questions that I linked to. Unfortunately, this is not suitable for this question. I'll update the OP with clarifications based on the comments. I'm looking more for the use cases where a language-user would want to have the false-negatives when comparing strings. The language provides this feature as consistency, now I would like us to go a step further. Perhaps thinking of this from the new-language designer, is it needed? (unfortunately, no lang-design.SE)

Comment: @Anonsage its not a false negative. They aren't the same object. That is all it is saying. I must also point out that in Java 8, `new String("foo") == new String("foo")` may be true (see [String Deduplication](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/08/string-deduplication-new-feature-java-8-update-20-2/)).

Comment: As to language design, [CS.SE](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7083/40980) advertises that it may be on topic there.

Comment: ooh, thank you! I will post my future lang-design questions there. :)

And, yeah, unfortunately 'false-negative' isn't the most accurate way to describe my question and what I'm looking for.. I need to write more words so people don't have to guess what I'm trying to say.

Comment: I could say 'false-negative for string value comparison', but I'm sure nobody wants that. And, cool, I didn't know about string deduplication yet

Comment: "Consistency within the language" also helps with generics

Comment: Well, I have to disagree about one premise of your question: String is a special case in Java, the only type having overloaded operators. At least, you really should work on your case for not overloading that operator too.

Comment: @Deduplicator The overloaded `+` operator is a mess and one that I've often seen misused resulting in megabytes of string allocation and garbage collection in short time frames. Yet, the `+` at compile time is an invaluable tool. However, Java does not allow *users* to overload operators, and that (thankfully) remains the case.

Comment: Well, with that update I just *have* to upvote now.

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't support operator overloading, which means `==` only applies to primitive types or references.  Anything else requires invocation of a method.  Why the designers did this is a question only they can answer.  If I had to guess, it's probably because operator overloading brings complexity they weren't interested in adding.

I'm no expert in C#, but the designers of that language appear to have set it up such that every primitive is a `struct` and every `struct` is an object.  Because C# allows operator overloading, that arrangement makes it very easy for any class, not just `String`, to make itself work in the "expected" way with any operator.  C++ allows the same thing.

Comment: "Java doesn't support operator overloading, which means == only applies to primitive types or references. Anything else requires invocation of a method.": One could add that if `==` meant string equality, we would need another notation for reference equality.

Comment: @Giorgio:  Exactly.  See my comment on Gilad Naaman's answer.

Comment: Although that can be solved by a static method that compares the references of two objects (or an operator). Like in C#, for example.

Comment: @GiladNaaman:  That would be a zero-sum game because it causes the opposite problem to what Java has now: equality would be on an operator and you'd have to invoke a method to compare references.  Further, you'd have to impose the requirement that all classes implement something that can be bound to `==`.  That's effectively adding operator overloading, which would have tremendous implications on the way Java is implemented.

Comment: @Blrfl: Not really. There will always be a defined way to compare reference (`ClassName.ReferenceEquals(a,b)`), and a default `==` operator and `Equals` method both pointing to `ReferenceEquals`.

Comment: @GiladNaaman:  C# has that.  Java doesn't.

Comment: @Blrfl: I know, I wish it had.

Comment: I think you can see a reference as a primitive type. In fact, primitive types are the only types that can be used in assignment, comparison (through `==`), and that can be passed (by value) as method arguments. This keeps the language simpler.

Comment: But `"hello " + "world!"` works, so this can't be the answer. Otherwise, why does `+` work on `String`s?

Comment: @AndresF.:  The concatenation (`+`) operator for strings is a special case that's built into the language.  To repeat the first sentence in the answer, Java does not provide facilities for general-purpose operator overloading.

Comment: @Blrfl Indeed, that was my point. Since `+` is a special case, so could have been `==`. Having it compare String references instead of comparing Strings has *nothing* to do with operator overloading.

Comment: @AndresF.:  See my earlier comment about why a special case for equality vs. reference comparison.

Comment: @Blrfl Sure. I'm saying the "Java has no operator overloading" part of your answer is a red herring.

Comment: @AndresF.:  You asked why `+` works on Strings and I explained why.  I would suggest that instead of carrying on the same discussion in the comments of three answers, you formulate your concerns into a question.

Comment: @Blrfl It was a rhetorical question; I'm not actually asking about `+` vs `==` (I know how they work and why, I'm not a Java novice), but instead pointing out it's false this is about operator overloading. Read the currently accepted answer to understand why.

Answer (score 2):

This has been made different in other languages.

In Object Pascal (Delphi/Free Pascal) and C#, the equality operator is defined to compare values, not references, when operating on strings.

Particularly in Pascal, **string is a primitive type** (one of the things I really love about Pascal, getting NullreferenceException just because of an uninitialized string is simply irritating) and have copy-on-write semantics thus making (most of time) string operations very cheap (in other words, only noticeable once you start concatenating multi-megabyte strings).

So, it's a language design decision for Java. When they designed the language they followed the C++ way (like Std::String) so strings are objects, which is IMHO an hack to compensate of C lacking an real string type, instead of making strings an primitive (which they are).

So for a reason why, I can only speculate they made that to easy on their side and not coding the operator make an exception on compiler to strings.

Comment: how does this answer the question asked?

Comment: See last sentence (which I separated in a proper paragraph in a edit).

Comment: IMHO, `String` should have been a primitive type in Java.  Unlike other types, the compiler needs to know about `String`; further, operations on it will be sufficiently common that for many kinds of application they may pose a performance bottleneck (which could be eased by native support).  A typical `string` [lowercase] would have an object allocated on the heap to hold its contents, but no "normal" reference to that object would exist anywhere; it could thus be a single-indirected `Char[]` or `Byte[]` rather than having to be a `Char[]` indirected through another object.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, there is no operator overloading whatsoever, and that's why the comparison operators are only overloaded for the primitive types.

The 'String' class is not a primitive, thus it does not have an overloading for '==' and uses the default of comparing the address of the object in the computer's memory.

I'm not sure, but I think that in Java 7 or 8 oracle made an exception in the compiler to recognize `str1 == str2` as `str1.equals(str2)`

Comment: "I'm not sure, but I think that in Java 7 or 8 oracle made an exception in the compiler to recognize str1 == str2 as str1.equals(str2)": I would not be surprised: Oracle seems to be less concerned with minimalism than Sun was.

Comment: If true, that's a very ugly hack since it means there's now one class the language treats differently from all others and breaks code that compares references.  :-@

Comment: @Blrfl: Yes, I agree, but I'm not sure that that's true. Just something from the top of my head. I'm searching for a source.

Comment: @Blrfl: How can it break code that compares references? Aren't two strings that have the same reference by necessity also equal?

Comment: @WillihamTotland:  Consider the opposite case.  Currently, if I create two strings, `s1` and `s2` and give them the same contents, they pass the equality (`s1.equals(s2)`) comparison but not the same-reference (`==`) comparison because they're two different objects.  Changing the semantics of `==` to mean equality would cause `s1 == s2` to evaluate `true` where it used to evaluate `false`.

Comment: @WillihamTotland: Yes, but not the other-way around. Two strings that are equal are *NOT* necessirily addressed by the same reference.

Comment: @Brlfl: While that is true, that sounds like an exceptionally bad thing to rely on in the first place, as strings are immutable, internable objects.

Comment: @WillihamTotland - more general, relying on object identity is a code smell. It is like not defining a primary key on a table in a SQL database and fuddling around with ROWIDs.

Comment: @Williham Totland: Then one should remove reference equality altogether. I think it should not be removed, for sure it shouldn't for mutable classes. For immutable classes I might want to know if an object is a copy of another object or if they are really the same object. It is Java, not Haskell.

Comment: @Giorgio: _"Java 7 or 8 oracle made an exception in the compiler to recognize str1 == str2 as str1.equals(str2)"_ Nope, the Java Language Specification says: [Reference Equality Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3): _"If the operands of an equality operator are both of either reference type or the null type, then the operation is object equality."_ That's all folks. I didn't find anything new about this in the [Java 8 early draft](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~mr/se/8/java-se-8-edr-spec.02.html) either.

Comment: But `"string " + "concatenation"` works, so this has nothing to do with `String` not being primitive or Java's lack of support for operator overloading. Operator `==` could have been built-in, just as with `+`.

Answer (score 0):

Java seems to have been designed to uphold a fundamental rule that the `==` operator should be legal any time one operand can be converted to the type of the other, and should compare the result of such conversion with the non-converted operand.

This rule is hardly unique to Java, but it has some far-reaching (and IMHO unfortunate) effects on the design of other type-related aspects of the language.  It would have been cleaner to specify the behaviors of `==` with regard to particular combinations of operand types, and forbid combinations of types X and Y where `x1==y1` and `x2==y1` wouldn't imply `x1==x2`, but languages seldom do that [under that philosophy, `double1 == long1` would either have to indicate whether `double1` is not an *exact* representation of `long1`, or else refuse to compile; `int1==Integer1` should be forbidden, but there should be a convenient and efficient non-throwing means of testing whether an object is a boxed integer with particular value (comparison with something that isn't a boxed integer should simply return `false`)].

With regard to applying the `==` operator to strings, if Java had forbidden direct comparisons between operands of type `String` and `Object`, it could have pretty well avoided surprises in the behavior of `==`, but there's no behavior it could implement for such comparisons that wouldn't be astonishing.  Having two string references kept in type `Object` behave differently from references kept in type `String` would have been far less astonishing than having either of those behaviors differ from that of a legal mixed-type comparison.  If `String1==Object1` is legal, that would imply that the only way for the behaviors of `String1==String2` and `Object1==Object2` to match `String1==Object1` would be for them to match each other.

Comment: I must be missing something, but IMHO `==` on objects should simply call (null-safe) equals and something else (e.g., `===` or `System.identityEqual`) should be used for the identity comparison. Mixing primitives and objects would be initially forbidden (there was no autoboxing before 1.5) and then some simple rule could be found (e.g. null-safe unbox, then cast, then compare).

Comment: @maaartinus: A good language design should use separate equality operators for value and reference equality.  While I agree that conceptually it would have been possible to have an `int==Integer` operator return `false` if the `Integer` is null, and otherwise compare values, that approach would have been unlike the behavior of `==` in all other circumstances, where it unconditionally coerces both operands to the same type before comparing them.  Personally I wonder if auto-unboxing was put in place in an effort to allow `int==Integer` to have a behavior that wasn't nonsensical...

Comment: ...since autoboxing the `int` and doing a reference comparison would have been silly [but wouldn't always fail].  Otherwise, I see no reason to allow an implicit conversion that can fail with an NPE.

Comment: I think that my idea is consistent. Just keep it mind that in the better world, `==` has nothing to do with `identityEquals`.

+++

"separate equality operators for value and reference equality" - but which ones? I'd consider both primitive `==` and `equals` as doing *value* comparison in the sense that `equals` looks at the *value* of the reference.

+++

When `==` meant `equals`, then `int==Integer` SHOULD do autoboxing and compare the references using null-safe equals.

+++

I'm afraid, my idea is not really mine, but just what Kotlin does.

Comment: @maaartinus: If `==` never tested reference equality, then it could sensibly perform a null-safe value-equality test.  The fact that it *does* test reference equality, however, severely limits how it can handle mixed reference/value comparisons without inconsistency.  Note also that Java is fixed on the notion that operators promote both operands to the same type, rather than yielding special behaviors based upon the combinations of types involved.  For example, `16777217==16777216.0f` returns `true` because it performs a lossy conversion of the first operand to `float`, while a...

Comment: ...comparison based upon actual numerical value with either convert both operands to `double`, or else test if converting the first operand to `float` yields the second *and* converting the second to `int` yields the first.  If Java doesn't accommodate special behaviors for mixed-type operators in cases like that, adding it for the less common reference-vs-primitive comparisons would seem less compelling.

Comment: If there's no good solution for the primitive to object comparison, then I'd simply forbid it. It'd be a special rule, but one which could bite nobody. +++ Claiming that `int` to `float` is not lossy is one of big Java mistakes (rarely anybody runs into this, but if so, it's pretty hard to find). If they didn't want to special case `1 + 2.0f` to return `double`, then they should simply forbid it; similarly for `16777217==16777216.0f`. +++ Also `lL + 2.0` should be forbidden, as there's no type to which both operands could converted to without real narrowing.

Comment: @maaartinus: Care to chat?  I agree with you that Java allows a number of things that IMHO should be forbidden; it also forbids some things which IMHO should be allowed.  I wish languages would include more primitive types for each storage format, depending upon whether types should try to behave like abstract numbers or machine-representable quantities.  Should a 32-bit floating-point declaration be viewed as saying "I want to hold an exact power-of-two fraction, or as "I want to hold a real number, but will *tolerate* `float` precision"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18754/discussion-between-maaartinus-and-supercat).

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is very good reason to want to be able to test if two object references point to the same object. I've had plenty of times that I've written

```
Address oldAddress;
Address newAddress;
... populate values ...
if (oldAddress==newAddress)
... etc ...
```

I may or may not have an equals function in such cases. If I do, the equals function may compare the entire contents of both objects. Often it just compares some identifier. "A and B are references to the same object" and "A and B are two different objects with the same content" are, of course, two very different ideas.

It's probably true that for immutable objects, like Strings, this is less of an issue. With immutable objects, we tend to think of the object and the value as being the same thing. Well, when I say "we", I mean "I", at least.

```
Integer three=new Integer(3);
Integer triangle=new Integer(3);
if (three==triangle) ...
```

Of course that returns false, but I can see someone thinking it should be true.

But once you say that == compares reference handles and not contents for Objects in general, making a special case for Strings would be potentially confusing. As someone else on here said, what if you wanted to compare the handles of two String objects? Would there be some special function to do it only for Strings?

And what about ...

```
Object x=new String("foo");
Object y=new String("foo");
if (x==y) ...
```

Is that false because they are two different objects, or true because they are Strings whose contents are equal?

So yes, I understand how programmers get confused by this. I've done it myself, I mean write if myString == "foo" when I meant if myString.equals("foo"). But short of redesigning the meaning of the == operator for all objects, I don't see how to address it.

Comment: Note that other modern languages on the JVM, such as Scala, use `==` to mean "equal strings".

Comment: @AndresF. (shrug) In Java, "<" means "less than", while in XML it "opens a tag". In VB "=" can mean "is equal to", while in Java it's only used for assignment. Etc. It's hardly surprising that different languages use different symbols to mean the same thing, or the same symbol to mean different things.

Comment: It wasn't a dig at your answer. It was just a comment. I was just pointing out that a more modern language than Java took the chance to redesign the meaning of `==`, just as you mentioned at the end.

Comment: @AndresF. And my reply wasn't a dig at your comment, just saying that different languages approach these issues in different ways. :-) I actually like the way VB handles this ... pause for the hisses and boos from the VB haters ... "=" always compares the value (for system-defined types), whether primitive or object. "Is" compares the handles of two objects. That seems more intuitive to me.

Comment: Sure. But Scala is way closer to Java than Visual Basic. I like to think Scala's designers realized that Java's use of `==` was error prone.

Comment: @AndresF. Ok, fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid question for `Strings`, and not only for strings, but also for other immutable Objects representing some "value", e.g. `Double`, `BigInteger`, and even `InetAddress`.

For making the `==` operator usable with Strings and other value-classes, I see three alternatives:

- Have the compiler know about all these value-classes and the way to compare their contents. If it were just a handful of classes from the `java.lang` package, I'd consider that, but that doesn't cover cases like InetAddress.
- Allow operator overloading so a class defines its `==` comparison behaviour.
- Remove the public constructors and have static methods returning instances from a pool, always returning the same instance for the same value. To avoid memory leaks, you need something like SoftReferences in the pool, which didn't exist in Java 1.0. And now, to maintain compatibility, the `String()` constructors can't be removed anymore.

The only thing that could still be done today would be to introduce operator overloading, and personally I don't wouldn't like Java to go that route.

To me, code readability is most important, and a Java programmer knows that the operators have a fixed meaning, defined in the language specification, whereas methods are defined by some code, and their meaning has to be looked up in the method's Javadoc. I'd like to stay with that distinction even if it means that String comparisons will not be able use the `==` operator.

There's just one aspect of Java's comparisons that's annoying to me: the effect of auto-boxing and -unboxing. It hides the distinction between the primitive and the wrapper type. But when you compare them with `==`, they are VERY different.

```
    int i=123456;
    Integer j=123456;
    Integer k=123456;
    System.out.println(i==j);  // true or false? Do you know without reading the specs?
    System.out.println(j==k);  // true or false? Do you know without reading the specs?
```